# Asp.Net Core 3.1 Controller method not calling

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-routing

I have Asp.net core 3.1 target application.so basically `HomeController` we are using View related action trigger and it's working fine.But i have another Get method called `PostData` in HomeController but it's not getting trigger.And always returning Index method View html in response.

Get Url:http://localhost:9062/Home/PostData?detail=test

**HomeController:**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public HomeController(StatelessServiceContext context)
    {
    }
    
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<string> PostData(string detail)//not getting call
    {
        return "PostData";
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
      {
        routes.MapRoute(
                  name: "default",
                  template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

        routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
                  name: "spa-fallback",
                  defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
      });
```

I have tried but not got yet how to resolve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure if it helps but UseMvc is really only for dotnet core 2.2 and below. You should use UseEndpoints instead: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#routing-startup-code

Comment: Have you tried like `[HttpGet("postdata")]` and when you call it `http://localhost:9062/PostData?detail=test`?

Comment: yes i tried ```[HttpGet("postdata")]``` but it's not working

Comment: @r08 and you called it like `http://localhost:9062/PostData?detail=test`?

Answer (score 0):

In your Startup.cs

```
app.UseMvc(configureRoutes => {
                configureRoutes.MapRoute(name: "default", template: "{controller=Login}/{action=Login}/{id?}");
            });
```

As you see your action method expects an id. Change your string detail to string id and it should work just fine.

Comment: already i have like configuration in startup cs file

Comment: try changing  
public async Task<string> PostData(string id)//not getting call
   {
       return "PostData";
    }

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> http://localhost:9062/Home/PostData?detail=test
> ```

First, please check your application configuration and the request URL, it is a `http` request, instead of `https`, are you changing your application to use `Http`? If not, try to change the request URL as below:

```
https://localhost:9062/Home/PostData?detail=test
```

Second, since you are using MapSpaFallbackRoute() method, your application is a SPA application, right? I have created a SPA application and checked your code(add the Home Controller and PostData action, then use the `[HttpGet()]` or `[HttpGet("postdata")]`), everything works well, the request url like this: `https://localhost:44332/Home/PostData?detail=test` or `https://localhost:44332/postdata?detail=test`.

I suggest you could try to remove the SPA route first, and check whether the MVC route is working or not. If still not working, can you create a new sample about it and share it via the Github or OneNote, so that we could reproduce it and help you fix it.